# Auto compleate google chrome form

Tags: html, google-chrome, model-view-controller

```
<div class="col-sm-12 input-group">
@using (Html.BeginForm("_BookTime", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="col-sm-12 FromFields">
        <b>Fulde navn:</b>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", @required = true })
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 FromFields">
        <b>Telefon:</b>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Phone, new { @class = "form-control", @required = true, @type = "number" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 FromFields">
        <b>Email:</b>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @required = true })
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 FromFields">
        <b>Post NR:</b>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Zip, new { @class = "form-control", @required = true, @type = "number" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 FromFields">
        <b>By:</b>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.City, new { @class = "form-control", @required = true })
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 FromFields">
        <b>Addresse:</b>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address, new { @class = "form-control", @required = true })
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 FromFields">
        <b>Vælg pakke</b>
        <select class="form-control" name="Package" required>
            @Html.Action("_PackageList", "home")
        </select>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <button id="SendBtn" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
}
```

Why won't google chrome auto complete the following formula? I have tried with giving them a name, and that wasn't working neither, so what am i doing wrong? usually this is done automatically, and i have never done **ANYTHING** form making google chrome do it for me. What can i do? Thanks

Comment: Try adding the `autocomplete="on"`attribute to your form elements.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add `autocomplete="off"` in your form

```
<form method="post" action="/form" autocomplete="off">

</form>
```

Comment: try adding individual on every input i.e <input type="text"  autocorrect="off">